# Pass request object to form instantion with Class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hi I want to use a [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/158/) with Class-based views, but instantion of this form must pass a `User` object ex.

```
theform = forms.PasswordReset(request.user,request.POST)
```

And here is a question, how to do this with Class-based views:

```
class UserChangePassword(FormView):
    form_class = PasswordReset
    template_name = 'profile/change_password.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_account')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options here:

Write your own `get_form` method.

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    return form_class(self.request.user, self.request.POST)
```

Write your own `get_form_kwargs` and update form's code.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(UserChangePassword, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user, 'post': self.request.POST})
    return kwargs
```

In this case you also need to update form to work properly with `kwargs` pairs.